# Excel VBA - Clicking on the workbook to unload a userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform that populates an excel worksheet but allows the tabs at the bottom of the workbook to be displayed. When a user clicks one of the tabs while the userform is opened, nothing happens. Is there a way to unload the userform whenever the user clicks on something that is not a part of the form?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way, although I'm a little skeptical about how well it will work in practice.  First set the ShowModal property of the Userform to False.  That will allow the user to click outside of the Userform and actually select something.

Next, put this code in the ThisWorkbook module

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    On Error Resume Next
        Unload UserForm1

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next
        Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

When a user clicks either a sheet tab or a cell in the active sheet, it will unload the userform.  There are probably a hundred other places the user could click that will not fire these events, but it may work for your situation.